# Javascript and HTML - onclick

Tags: javascript, html, input, onclick, radio-button

Suppose I have the following code which creates two radio buttons:

```
<li id="foli517"        class="     ">
<label class="desc" id="shippingChoice" for="Field517_0">
    Shipping Options
        </label>
<div>
<input id="shippingChoice" name="Field517" type="hidden" value="" />
    <span>
<input id="shipping1"       name="Field517"         type="radio"        class="field radio"         value="$2.00 Shipping Fee"      tabindex="13"                        checked="checked"                      />
<label class="choice" for="Field517_0"      >
    $2.00 Shipping Fee</label>
    </span>
    <span>
<input id="Field517_1"      name="Field517"         type="radio"        class="field radio"         value="I will pick up the items (free shipping)"        tabindex="14"                               />
<label class="choice" for="Field517_1"      >
    I will pick up the items (free shipping)</label>
    </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

How would I implement a javascript function onclick which updates the inner html of a span with id "mySpan" with the word "FREE" when the 2nd radio button is clicked, and "NOT FREE" otherwise?

```
document.getElementById(WHAT GOES HERE).onclick = function() { 
    //what goes here?
};
```

Comment: Could you please improve the code formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('foli517').onchange = function(e) {
    var e = e || event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var span = document.getElementById('mySpan');
    var span2 = document.getElementById('mySpan2');

    if (target.type === "radio") {
        span.innerHTML = (target.id === "Field517_1") ? "FREE" : "NOT FREE";
    }
    if (target.type === "checkbox") {
        span2.innerHTML = "Is it checked? " + target.checked;
    }
};
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pEYnm/2/

Comment: This worked perfectly. Could you show me an example for a checkbox? How do I see if a checkbox is set to true or false? (clicked or not clicked)

Comment: @reising1: Updated. The property  you use to get the checked status is simply `checked`.

Comment: I currently have: var isChecked = this.checked; and it is always false

Comment: If you're using my code above, it is using event delegation, so the handler is on the container. As such you'd need `target.checked`. If your code is different, I'd need to see that code.

Answer (score 0):

I would add onclick="setSpan('FREE');" and onclick="setSpan('NOT FREE');" to HTML of the respective radio buttons then add a javascript function as below that sets the HTML of the span.

```
function setSpan(text) {
   document.getElementById('mySpan').innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: like this?: <input id="Field517_1"   name="Field517"   type="radio"   class="field radio"   value="I will pick up the items (free shipping)"   tabindex="14"    onclick="setShippingSpan('$0.00');"     />

Comment: Exactly. I think it is easier to do this than add onEvent handlers etc.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working. I've confirmed that my span id is correct.

Comment: Did you update the name of the function i gave you to be setShippingSpan instead of setSpan? And have you included this in the page? Try using the developer tools of Google Chrome or safari to see if a javascript error has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Working code of Radio button on click](http://jsfiddle.net/ravikiranj/AnaLh/) !